# Inherit interface class only if template type match concept

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++20, c++-concepts

I have an `ISerializable` interface with pure virtual `read` and `write` functions. I also have a `List<T>` class. So, my question is: can I inherit my `List<T>` from `ISerializable` only if `T` is also inherit from `ISerializable`?

usage example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class ISerializable
{
public:
    virtual void read(std::istream& stream) = 0;
    virtual void write(std::ostream& stream) = 0;
};

class A : public ISerializable {
public:
    void read(std::istream& stream) override {}
    void write(std::ostream& stream) override {}
};
class B {};

template<typename T>
class List : public ISerializable
{
public:
    void read(std::istream& stream) override
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            items[i].read(stream);
        }
    }

    void write(std::ostream& stream) override
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            items[i].write(stream);
        }
    }

private:
    std::array<T, 10> items;
};

int main()
{
    List<A> list_a;
    //List<B> list_b; <- error here
}
```

Comment: Like this https://godbolt.org/z/bos6jb4rW?

Comment: @kiner_shah - What about the "only if" bit ?

Comment: Easy solution might be something as `template <typename T> class List : public std::conditional_t<std::is_base_of_v<ISerializable,T>, ISerializable, ???>...`. Only problem is that in case of false condition, you need to derive from some other base, such as some helper empty `INonSerializable` class.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I am unsure of the question actually, I was trying to confirm whether my understanding is correct. Seems it's not correct :-)

Comment: @kiner_shah kind of. I expanded your snippet: https://godbolt.org/z/73MhjbWxo

Comment: @DanielLangr requires clause is not allowed on virtual functions

Comment: @Espeon Don't understand your comment. Where do I talk about the requires clasue?

Comment: @DanielLangr if I conditionally inherit `ISerializable`, I must override `read`/`write` functions in any case. The goal is to make these functions unavailable if templated class does not allow them, so I tried to also use `requires` clause to make them available only when `T` is serializable

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed set up something like that up in C++20.

```
template<typename T>
class List : public ListCommon<T> {
};

template<std::derived_from<ISerializable> S>
class List<S> : public ListCommon<S>, public ISerializable {
  // Implement the serialization
};
```

The specialization for a serialziable type is only viable with the added constraint of the type being derived from `ISerializable` (checked with the standard `std::derived_from` concept).

`ListCommon` is where I would place the common implementation details to avoid repeating them upon specialization.

Comment: This works if you have exactly one interface you want to conditionally support, but becomes unwieldy if there are multiple

Comment: As an option, maybe, but as Caleth told, it becomes complicated when there are more such interfaces

Comment: @Espeon - Multiple interfaces makes this a different ball game (and isn't really what you asked, is it?) `ListCommon` is one way to pull common implementation details to be reused `ListSer` can be another base. But you'll need more boiler-plate that is outside the scope of what you posed.

Comment: I believe this is where somebody comes in and points out that they should just rewrite it in Rust because `impl<T> Serialize for List<T> where T: Serialize { ... }` is pretty snazzy.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple and easy-extensible solution. In my actual project I have more data containers than only `List` and my `List` have a lot of different constructors and static factories that I have to extend. I still hope, there is some simple inherit & implement solution, but if no one will post it soon, I'll mark this answer as correct

Comment: @Espeon - You can always just ask a followup question. Present the problem you want to solve in precise terms, and let people work with all the details about your constraints.

Comment: @Barry - I started on Rust a year ago, and now I need to get back to it because of that comment :) The more you know...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this solution fits if you already have a lot of classes that you don't really want to refactor and/or duplicate. The disadvantage here is that IDE will not be able to assist you sometimes. However, since it implies one of main features of concepts, it is still legal. Just be careful!

Here we have an interface that explicitly requires some functions to be implemented and a concept that also requires same functions to be implemented. Prefer interface over the concept! If you inherit interface, IDE will assist you in function overloading. Concept is needed if you want to use interface as a parameter type later (see utility class example). This is an example of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

```
class ISerializable
{
public:
    virtual void write_to_stream(std::ostream& stream) const = 0;
    virtual void read_from_stream(std::istream& stream) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
concept ImplicitlySerializable = requires(const T a1, T a2, std::ostream os, std::istream is)
{
    a1.write_to_stream(os);
    a2.read_from_stream(is);
};

template<typename T>
concept Serializable = std::derived_from<T, ISerializable> || ImplicitlySerializable<T>;
```

Some utility functions to handle any object that match concept

```
class StreamUtils
{
public:
    template<Serializable T>
    static void write(std::ostream& stream, const T& value)
    {
        value.write_to_stream(stream);
    }

    template<Serializable T>
    static void read(std::istream& stream, T& to)
    {
        to.read_from_stream(stream);
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
// Interface usage
class Animal : public ISerializable
{
    void write_to_stream(std::ostream& stream) override
    {
        // serialization code here
    }

    void read_from_stream(std::istream& stream) override
    {
        // deserialization code here
    }
}

// Concept usage
template<typename T>
class List
{
    void write_to_stream(std::ostream& stream) const requires Serializable<T>
    {
        // serialization code here
    }

    void read_from_stream(std::istream& stream) requires Serializable<T>
    {
        // deserialization code here
    }
{

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file("my_file.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios:binary);
    StreamUtils::write(file, Animal());
    StreamUtils::write(file, List<Animal>());
}
```